# Удаление файлов по регулярке

Tags: файлы

Бывают ситуации, когда из папки нужно удалить все файлы с определенным суффиксом. Как это сделать с помощью одной комманды в vifm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно обнаружил такую возможность с помощью поиского фильтра в `vifm`. Делается это примерно так:

```
=some_pattern
```

при наборе все неподходящие под этот паттерн файлы и папки будут скрыты, после чего вы можете выбрать все оставшиееся и удалить